# Azure API Manager ARM template - vnet questions

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have specified in my ARM template the below syntax in the APImanager and have a few issues.

1. When I look at the API manager after it is deployed, it has a public VIP (along with internal IP.). How come the public IP is being setup?
2. When I look at the virtual network tab on the portal, it shows internal selected and my subnet but shows the vnet as select virtual network, seemingly indicating it isn't setup.
3. How can I specify a static internal IP for APIM gateway to use to I can safely setup internal hostnames?
4. I've read the APIM needs to be in its own subnet, which is fine, however does this actually utilize any IP addresses aside the one it is assigned, is it safe to use the smallest allowable Azure subnet regardless of SKU?

> ```
>             "virtualNetworkType": "Internal",
>             "virtualNetworkConfiguration": {
>                 "subnetResourceId": "[variables('subnetRef')]",
>                 "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
>                 "vnetid":"[variables('vnetID')]"
>             }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you share the whole template? You cannot have API Management in the VNet and with a Public IP, its either one of those.
2. Again please share the template (or consult [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-api-management-create-with-vnet/azuredeploy.json) proper example and fix your template)
3. Since its a PaaS service I dont think you can
4. I've never seen any mentions of API Management using more than one IP address, so I assume the answer is yes

Comment: My template is exactly like that example with the exception of the hostnameConfigurations section does not exist in my template. And "virtualNetworkType": "External", is set to internal instead. I'll include actual template tomorrow.

Comment: i guess you should use external, since this is what it has to be, actually, when i think about the `hostname` section it might be you need more than one IP address if you want more than one hostname, but I've never used API Management in this setup, so I dont know for sure